# What order were files/directories output in dir?

Tags: ms-dos

In the version of command.com included with MS-DOS, `DIR` seems to print files in a random order, but if one runs multiple `DIR` commands, they all print the files in the same order. This order does not appear to be based on date, size, or alphabetization. So what is the order? Does it simply print whatever files it finds first?

Comment: related: [Default file order of "dir" command in Windows console](https://superuser.com/q/481570/241386), [What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=1603)

Comment: As an early DOS user (1.0, I think) it used to bug me that it would not show files and later (in DOS 2.0 and above) folders in alphabetical order.  Norton Utilities solved that by providing ds.com (.exe?) or dirsort which allowed you to do just that, sort your files and folders in whatever order you prefered, with an /s switch to do sub-folders as well.  I think I used ds more than any other command before the version of DOS came out where alphabetical was the default order.  I used ts (textsearch) a lot, too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When a new file is created in a FAT-based file system, its entry will be placed in the first vacant directory slot, if there is one, or else the directory will be extended to add another cluster worth of vacant slots if possible (and the new entry will be placed in the first of those).  If no files are ever deleted, files will be assigned directory entries in the order of creation.

Before the advent of long file names, each file that was deleted would result in an empty directory slot, which would get filled by the next file to be created.  Long file names complicate this process because they are stored using multiple consecutive directory slots (though I don't know the exact process).

The "dir" command in MS-DOS defaults to reporting files in the same order as their directory entries, but command-line arguments in later versions allow sorting by various criteria.

Comment: Some details about long file names, by Raymond Chen: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110826-00/?p=9793

Comment: And with the knowledge that new entries will be placed in the first vacant slot, you could actually manually order the directory with carefully ordered `DEL` and `COPY` operations (I have done that).

Comment: "_or else the directory will be extended to add another cluster worth of vacant slots_" Apart from the root directory, which – if I remember correctly – couldn't be extended. Again, IIRC, with standard tools, the root-dir-size was fixed on floppies (7 clusters, 112 entries in most cases) but I seem to remember you could alter the size when formatting a hard-drive.

Comment: @TripeHound: Added "if possible" to the sentence.  If it's possible to create a file, it will be ordered as described, but as you note that might not always be possible.

Answer (score 22):

`DIR` lists files in the order they’re returned by the [find first](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/89/29.html) and [find next](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/91/29.html) calls.

On FAT file systems, RAM drives, CD-ROMs etc. this is the order of the directory entries on disk, which on FAT file systems is file creation order as long as no files are deleted. On network file systems, it’s whatever order the server and redirector choose. Other file system drivers can exhibit different behaviour; thus on [HPFS](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bolo/shipyard/hpfs.html) and NTFS, which sort directories’ contents on disk, files are returned in the file systems sort order (as can be seen in OS/2 or Windows virtual DOS boxes on HPFS or NTFS volumes).

There are tools which will re-order entries on disk, to provide a permanent sort order for `DIR`. Defragmenting could also re-order files (commonly, directories first, then files).

DOS 5 added various sorting options to `DIR` itself; the order then depends only on those, when present.

Comment: A VDM in OS/2 or Windows NT was a third case, halfway between.  Local disc volumes weren't presented as network redirected, but neither were the underlying filesystems unsorted.  They were often HPFS or NTFS where directories are sorted by their nature.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever it finds first.  `DIR` in MS-DOS `command.com` starts at the beginning of the directory table and reads it through to the end.  The files will be in the order they were added to the directory table.

Comment: *"The files will be in the order they were added to the directory table."* If the other two answers are correct, that's not strictly true. Rather, the files would be in the order in which *they exist* in the directory entries list. Is that what you meant, or are you proposing an answer different from that of the other two currently existing answers?